# I cannot run my second test in JUnit, it shows "session not created"

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

when i try to run my test in appium, my second test is not running. Its shows "A new session could not be created". My second test function name is BAddon, while second test execution the error thrown

Here is my code

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class FirstAutomate {
private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    //File app = new File("C:\\sdk\\platform-tools\\Myapp.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.0.2"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","G3 Beat");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.myapp.app");
     capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.myapp.app.screens.prehomescreens.activities.SplashScreen");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");

     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    //capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

   @Test
   public void AppLogin() throws InterruptedException {
  //Tapping login button
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   driver.findElement(By.id("loginButtonTextView")).click();
   //User inputs mail id
      driver.findElement(By.id("emailIdEditText")).sendKeys("rag1@mail.com");
   //User login button click
   driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtnRCB")).click();
    //User inputs OTP
   driver.findElement(By.id("pinPadContainer")).sendKeys("123456");
   WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("nextBtnRCB"));
   if(loginBtn.isDisplayed())
   {
       loginBtn.click();
   }else
   {
       System.out.println("Button is not present");
   }
   Thread.sleep(15000);
   }



  @Test
  public void BAddOn() throws InterruptedException{

//Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement AddonBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("studentStatusButton"));
if(AddonBtn.isDisplayed())
{
AddonBtn.click();   
}else{
    System.out.println("AddOnBtn is not visible");
}

}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess setup is called before every test case. Once the server is running you don't need setup to be called again.

You need to figure out a way so that appium server setup is only called once before the execution of ur test cases begin. I think there is `@BeforeClass` annotation to do that.

Comment: Of course the author of the question chooses the answer, but in this case I would disagree that this is the best answer from the three.
This particular solution assumes that end state of the first test matches the start state of the second one which adds risk for future tests. If your first test fails in the middle, the second one will too.
You are launching a test session, NOT a server so I would disagree that this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are missing driver closure after the test - you try to launch new session when first one is already there. Try adding following code:

```
@After
public static shutdown() {
    driver.quit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you are attempting to create a new driver object. This occurs due to the flow of JUNIT given the annotations.

`Before
Test
After
Before
Test
After
ect`

To fix this you either need to create an @After method which closes the last driver ie.:

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
     driver.quit();
}
```

Or not create a driver in a before clause. Instead you can create the driver in a BeforeClass function ie.

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
     //create driver
}
```

As it has been mention, these are not the best ways to instantiate a driver. Instead it would be better to have a class which holds your driver object. Lets call this class `DriverContainer`, driver container then has a `getDriver` method which can be used to instantiate or return a driver depending on whether or not a driver exists via if-else statements or switch statements. This way whenever you use a driver you are more sure that it is the proper driver which did not crash, timeout or turn into null.